# Android Clean Code: Handle Click Events in complex GridView

Tags: android, coding-style

not sure if SO is the right place for this kind of question but here it goes.

I find it relatively hard to write clean code in Android. One problem I struggle with repeatedly are click events in GridView items. Say I have a complex layout (in a custom UI-element) that I inflate for each GridView item that contains multiple Buttons. A button click yields multiple events like database modifications, display of dialogs etc.

If I would handle click events inside those UI elements this would look like as follows:

```
Fragment -> GridViewAdapter -> MyGridViewItem -> OnClickButton1() -> modifyDB()
```

I don't want the MyGridViewItem to know about any DB modifications or stuff like that. Or in other words: I don't want to handle those events deep down in my code, but I'm not sure how else to handle them.

Should I use an interface and let either my Adapter or the fragment that creates that adapter implement that interface? Is this considered clean architecture? I couldn't find a clean architecture tutorial that uses adapters and complex layouts.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you considered using events (for ex. `EventBus`) ?

Comment: @R.Kirill hm but the problem remains. Where should I handle the event? Say each item represents an object (e.g. a person) should I pass that person instance to the event listener? And if so is it a cleaner approach to handle all those events inside the Adapter or the Fragment? Cheers

Comment: if I had to choose between `Adapter` and `Fragment`, I'd go with Fragment for sure. But it doesn't look good still, because `modifyDB()` is business logic and it should be distinguished from the `View`, which is `Fragment`. Do you use `MVP` in your project? If so, I'd say that it is `Presenter's` responsibility to handle click events and then delegate business logic stuff and update the UI if required

Comment: @R.Kirill So, listen for a ClickEvent inside the Fragment and pass it to the Fragment's controller for further processing (e.g. DB)? Say I have to modify the GridViewItem as well (e.g. icon state), this would be done directly inside the view before I trigger the event, wouldn't it? Btw.: Can you recommend a good comprehensive intro to MVP where complexe scenarios like the one above are discussed?